# Javascript - Page reloads after selecting photo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

recently some of my website users reported that when they trying to upload an image, after selecting photo from gallery the page crashes and reloads from the first. I noticed that all of them are using old phones with old browsers, but normally it shouldn't happen.
One of the users has sent me an screenshot of his browser after this problem. Here is the picture : [image: error screenshot]

In new browsers there is no problem and everything works fine.

I'm using https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs crop library for client-side cropping purpose.

I don't know which line of my code causes this crash and reload please help me.

Here is my code :

```
$("#uploader").on("change",function(){
var files = this.files;
var file;
if (files && files.length) {
    file = files[0];
    var type = file.type;
    if (/^image\/\w+$/.test(type)) {
      uploadedImageName = file.name;
      uploadedImageType = type;
      if (uploadedImageURL) {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(uploadedImageURL);
      }
      uploadedImageURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      showCropModal();
      $("#uploader").val('');
    }
  }})

function showCropModal(){ 
try{
    $('#crop-image').cropper('destroy').attr('src', uploadedImageURL).cropper({
          viewMode : 2,
          aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
          strict:true,
          background:false,
          minCropBoxWidth:150,
          minCropBoxHeight:100, 
          autoCropArea : 1,
          zoomOnTouch : false,
          crop: function(e) {
          }
      });
      $(".overlay-page").addClass('overlay-open');
      isCropping = true;
}catch(e){
      alertify.error("error reading image,please try again");
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what errors are occurring do you have access to error logs? What defines an 'old' browser? Have you tried testing this or are you just assuming what someone sent you is correct.

Comment: Try removing lines of code until it stops causing errors. That might help narrow down the offending code.